# The query does not start with a valid identifier, has to be either SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE FROM

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink

When running this query:

```
SELECT a.recordId
FROM Study a
WHERE a.recordId IN (
        SELECT c.col1
        FROM xyz c
        WHERE c.col1 = 'param1'
            AND c.col2 = 'param2'
        )
```

I get this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
>   Exception Description: Syntax error parsing []. 
>   [0, 0] The query does not start with a valid identifier, has to be either SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE FROM.
>
> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
>   Exception Description: Syntax error parsing []. 
>   [0, 0] The query does not start with a valid identifier, has to be either SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE FROM.
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:334)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1614)
>       ... 75 more

found these links

- https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/368031/
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=420955

where newer builds are released of jpa, however my org is using older one I guess. Please help me with some other work around

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226491/eclipse-indigo-jpa-validation-problems  https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/368031/

Comment: Your problem is that the query string you actually supply is empty.

Comment: Hi prdp,sorry i dint get you, it looks the same way as above

Comment: Hi marko, query string u mean params?

Comment: I am giving the params, col1 ='param1' and col2='param2'

Comment: I tried to edit but couldn't, i mention here, thanks in advance to all, need help.

Comment: You _think_ you're passing in the query string you posted, but what the program actually observes is `[]`---an empty string.

Comment: I have the same query above it, but for other entity which is working fine, with same params in same method, i am not getting why for immediate next line with same query it is giving error

Comment: The problem is as u can see, i expect only recordId to be returned, but somehow the jpa is converting it to many attributes, like record_id, login_id from Studies  like that, any one please tel me why this is happening

Comment: Marko , can u please suggest me any solution?

Comment: Show the code, as we can't guess what you are actually passing in to the createQuery call, or why it might not parse it correctly.  The bug you linked is using the wrong method to create a query, resulting in an invalid string being used, and the error shows the String passed in.